# Is it possible to integrate Shibboleth Login flow in iPhone using NSURLConnection or UIWebview?

Tags: ios, uiwebview, nsurlconnection, shibboleth

I want to know what exactly Shibboleth Login is and why it is required? Can we implement Shibboleth Login inside iPhone or iPad application? If yes the how.

I found very few details on google as well as here on stackoverflow only one question was somewhat helpful.

Anyone can explain in detail will be very helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It appears this has been doable for a while: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1935011/integrating-iphone-application-with-shibboleth